# Display presigned s3 url of type mov in the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Generated a presigned URL and trying to display it in the browser by overriding response-content-type header.

But mov fileType is not getting displayed in the browser.

```
val generatePresignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucket, key)
            .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .withExpiration(expiration)
            .also { 
                it.addRequestParameter("response-content-type", "video/quicktime") }
            }
return s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)
```

Tried response-content-type like "video/mp4", in which case, the video is getting downloaded but not displayed in the browser.

Any help here would be really great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tested a content-disposition header of inline vs. attachment?